# Error compiling a QT app for Windows with Github Actions

Tags: qt, qt5, github-actions

Im trying to make Github Actions compile my project on windows, but it is failing. When compiling in my machine, it compiles fine. Why does it fail on Github Actions?

I have also tried installing QT using jurplel/install-qt-action@v2.5.3, but I get the same error

The project compiles fine for Mac and Linux

Compile Output:

```
Info: creating stash file D:\a\dsda-launcher\dsda-launcher\dsda-launcher\build\.qmake.stash
24
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe -f Makefile.Release
25
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/a/dsda-launcher/dsda-launcher/dsda-launcher/build'
26
'C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin\uic.exe' ../mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
27
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DAPP_NAME=dsda-launcher -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CONCURRENT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I../../dsda-launcher -I. -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtConcurrent -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore -Irelease -I. -I/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release/main.o ../main.cpp
28
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DAPP_NAME=dsda-launcher -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CONCURRENT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I../../dsda-launcher -I. -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtConcurrent -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore -Irelease -I. -I/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release/mainwindow.o ../mainwindow.cpp
29
../mainwindow.cpp: In function 'QString lowerCase(std::__cxx11::string)':
30
../mainwindow.cpp:77:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
31
     for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
32
                 ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
33
../mainwindow.cpp: In constructor 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
34
../mainwindow.cpp:211:34: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
35
                     for(int i=0;i<tp.length();i++) // Loop the chars to find the 4 quotes
36
                                 ~^~~~~~~~~~~~
37
../mainwindow.cpp:266:42: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
38
                             for(int i=0;i<tp.length();i++)
39
                                         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~
40
../mainwindow.cpp:308:46: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
41
                                 for(int i=0;i<tp.length();i++)
42
                                             ~^~~~~~~~~~~~
43
../mainwindow.cpp: In member function 'void MainWindow::on_LaunchGameButton_clicked(bool, bool)':
44
../mainwindow.cpp:881:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
45
             for(int i=0; i<dehFiles.length();i++)
46
                          ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
47
../mainwindow.cpp:893:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
48
             for(int i=0; i<files.length();i++)
49
                          ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
50
In file included from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:65,
51
                 from ../mainwindow.cpp:1068:
52
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/excpt.h:14:8: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
53
 extern "C" {
54
        ^~~
55
In file included from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:6,
56
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
57
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
58
                 from ../mainwindow.cpp:1068:
59
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/specstrings.h:18:8: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
60
 extern "C" {
61
        ^~~
62
In file included from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
63
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
64
                 from ../mainwindow.cpp:1068:
65
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:19:8: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
66
 extern "C" {
67
        ^~~
68
In file included from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/x86intrin.h:27,
69
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:1554,
70
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:163,
71
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
72
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
73
                 from ../mainwindow.cpp:1068:
74
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ia32intrin.h:55:25: error: expected '}' before end of line
75
 #pragma GCC push_options
76
                         ^
77
../mainwindow.cpp:751:1: note: to match this '{'
78
 {
79
 ^
80
In file included from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/x86intrin.h:27,
81
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:1554,
82
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/minwindef.h:163,
83
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:8,
84
                 from C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:69,
85
                 from ../mainwindow.cpp:1068:
86
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ia32intrin.h: At global scope:
87
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/ia32intrin.h:55:25: error: expected declaration before end of line
88
 #pragma GCC push_options
89
                         ^
90
make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:725: release/mainwindow.o] Error 1
91
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/a/dsda-launcher/dsda-launcher/dsda-launcher/build'
92
make: *** [Makefile:45: release] Error 2
```

Github Actions code:

```
steps:
      - name: Install qt
        run: |
          choco install qt5-default
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: build
        run: |
          C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin\qmake.exe ..
          make.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to call `#include <windows.h>` before including any other header. I don't know why, but it works.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/38780/solved-errors-with-windows-h